# Way of Join Method and number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in.. Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert my mysql_* to PDO but cannot achieve this. I keep receiving *"SQLSTATE[HY093]: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in"* error. But before asking this let me ask you for another advice:

I have got 3 tables: STUDENTS - LESSONBOUGHT and ACCOUNT
And within my INNODB, I connected lessonsbought_id and account_id with students_id. Also I had students_id column in *"lessonsbought"* and *"account"* tables as well. And in my old mysql_* codes I was using Left Join to show results based on this common *"students_id"* row..

But now, after having *"SQLSTATE[HY093]: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in"* error I tried to connect upon foreign key to show the results like :

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM students s1 LEFT JOIN lessonsbought l1 ON s1.students_id  = l1.lessonsbought_id LEFT JOIN account a1 ON s1.students_id = a1.account_id")as $row)
```

The old version was :

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM students s1 LEFT JOIN lessonsbought l1 ON s1.students_id  = l1.students_id LEFT JOIN account a1 ON s1.students_id = a1.students_id")as $row)
```

Firstly, which one is better?

And my second question: How can I shape my insert codes on my insert data page? (This example was tried to be converted from mysql_* version)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    try{
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MY-DB-NAME;charset=utf8','MY-DB-USERNAME','MY-DB-PASSWORD');
    }
    catch(PDOException $exc)
    {echo 'Failed while insert operation'. $exc->getMessage(); 
      exit();
    }


    $students_name = $_POST['students_name'];       
    $students_phone = $_POST['students_phone']; 
    $students_email = $_POST['students_email']; 
    $students_status = $_POST['students_status']; 
    $students_first_level = $_POST['students_first_level']; 
    $students_reg_date = $_POST['students_reg_date'];  

    $lessonsbought_lesson_type = $_POST['lessonsbought_lesson_type'];       
    $lessonsbought_total_hours = $_POST['lessonsbought_total_hours']; 

    $account_all_cost = $_POST['account_all_cost'];       
    $payment_method = $_POST['payment_method']; 
    $discount = $_POST['discount']; 
    $payment_done = $_POST['payment_done']; 
    $payment_waiting = $_POST['payment_waiting']; 

    $pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO students(students_name,students_phone,students_email,students_status,students_first_level,students_reg_date) VALUES (:students_name,:students_phone,:students_email,:students_status,:students_first_level,:students_reg_date)";
    $last_id = $db->lastInsertId();
    $pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO lessonsbought(lessonsbought_lesson_type,lessonsbought_total_hours,students_id) VALUES (:lessonsbought_lesson_type,:lessonsbought_total_hours,:last_id)";
    $pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO account(account_all_cost,payment_method,discount,payment_done,payment_waiting,students_id) VALUES (:account_all_cost,:payment_method,:discount,:payment_done,:payment_waiting,:last_id)";


    $pdoResult = $db->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":students_name"=>$students_name,":students_phone"=>$students_phone,":students_email"=>$students_email,":students_status"=>$students_status,":students_first_level"=>$students_first_level,":students_reg_date"=>$students_reg_date,
    ":lessonsbought_lesson_type"=>$lessonsbought_lesson_type,":lessonsbought_total_hours"=>$lessonsbought_total_hours,":students_id"=>$last_id,
    ":account_all_cost"=>$account_all_cost,":payment_method"=>$payment_method,":discount"=>$discount,":payment_done"=>$payment_done,":payment_waiting"=>$payment_waiting,":students_id"=>$last_id));

    if($pdoExec)
    {
        echo 'Success! Data Insert Done';
    }else{
        echo 'Failed While Data Insert Operation';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: table name updated from "muhasebe" to "account"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, it doesn't make sense to join `students.student_id` with `lessonsbought.lesson_id`. Those columns don't relate to each other at all. You should use the foreign key in you join, so it should be `ON s1.student_id = l1.student_id`. And the same when joining `students` with `accounts`.

Every time you assign to `$pdoQuery`, you're replacing the previous value. So when you call `$db->prepare($pdoQuery);` it's just preparing the last query, which is the `INSERT INTO muhasebe`, and it has 6 placeholders. Then when you call `$pdoResult->execute()`, your array has values for the placeholders from the other queries, but you get an error because this query doesn't have those placeholders.

PDO doesn't allow you to combine multiple queries in a single call. You need to make a separate `execute()` call for each query:

```
$pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO students(students_name,students_phone,students_email,students_status,students_first_level,students_reg_date) VALUES (:students_name,:students_phone,:students_email,:students_status,:students_first_level,:students_reg_date)";
$pdoResult = $db->prepare($pdoQuery);
$pdoResult->execute(array(":students_name"=>$students_name,":students_phone"=>$students_phone,":students_email"=>$students_email,":students_status"=>$students_status,":students_first_level"=>$students_first_level,":students_reg_date"=>$students_reg_date));
$last_id = $db->lastInsertId();

$pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO lessonsbought(lessonsbought_lesson_type,lessonsbought_total_hours,students_id) VALUES (:lessonsbought_lesson_type,:lessonsbought_total_hours,:students_id)";
$pdoResult = $db->prepare($pdoQuery);
$pdoResult->execute(array(":lessonsbought_lesson_type"=>$lessonsbought_lesson_type,":lessonsbought_total_hours"=>$lessonsbought_total_hours,":students_id"=>$last_id));

$pdoQuery ="INSERT INTO muhasebe(account_all_cost,payment_method,discount,payment_done,payment_waiting,students_id) VALUES (:account_all_cost,:payment_method,:discount,:payment_done,:payment_waiting,:students_id)";
$pdoResult = $db->prepare($pdoQuery);
$pdoResult->execute(array(":account_all_cost"=>$account_all_cost,":payment_method"=>$payment_method,":discount"=>$discount,":payment_done"=>$payment_done,":payment_waiting"=>$payment_waiting,":students_id"=>$last_id));
```